# Typescript: How do I properly type an array composed of n N-tuples and m M-tuples?

Tags: typescript

```
//An N-tuple (quadruple?) that is a subset of a row
type Quadruple = [string, string, number, boolean];

//A value that is a subset of a row
type Value = [string];

//A row in the format [...Quadruple[], ...Value[]]
type Row = (string | boolean | number)[]; //this works...but information is lost.

const egRow1: Row = ["id", "name", 1, true, "id2", "name2", 1, true, "id3", "name3", 1, false, "value1", "value2"];
const egRow2: Row = ["id", "name", 1, true, "id2", "name2", 1, true, "value1", "value2"];
const egRow3: Row = ["id", "name", 1, true, "value1", "value2"];
```

How can I type a row effectively to encode the fact that it is composed of M `Quadruples` followed by N `Values`?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that this can only be done by enumerating all possible quantities (M) of `Quadruple` and union these types:

```
type Row1 = [string, string, number, boolean, ...Array<string>];
type Row2 = [string, string, number, boolean, string, string, number, boolean, ...Array<string>];
type Row3 = [string, string, number, boolean, string, string, number, boolean, string, string, number, boolean, ...Array<string>];
...
type RowM = [string, string, number, boolean, ..., ...Array<string>];

type Row = Row1 | Row2 | Row3  | ... | RowM;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=5&ssc=31&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gdwIxQLxQNoGdgCcCWAdgOYA0UOBJ5hArgLYBGEu5jccANhAIaHkA6IQEFcuHiAA8lIsQB8AXQDcAKFCRYiAExpMM6hTyyaDZqyjsuvfoaplbxqHSYs2Hbn0EixE6UZKKqurQ8AgAzLrY-vb69s5mblaeDgaxJi7mlh42aSlxpq4W7tZeAqLiUrGBKmrgIYi6oSgAPpoIOq2hYaoqAMZwhDhQEMRNAFxtkQBE+AAmU+RThDz0EAtQSOR4tBCLc1rrSysQB+SbUNu7UDOzYYfLq3dn5ABmPJxYV1MAbu87SIdfpwdgdlH0BkMRqEtBNQtM5vdjutzpc9rNTtcHidkVtcDtFkD-oC-tiwf1BsBhqNEGFYQ10BgbojVjiLnivoSIACCSTQT1yZCxHBcEg6Qh4fNFljWajrvtkWSIZSWLhhTDJgymVKkc8oFo0RipsAIDgpoqKcMhbhaRrMOcjizdbKboasRiUey0U9Mcdvec3h8vi8sMGeGalEA)

Answer (score 2):

In typescript 4.0 you can use Variadic Tuple Types [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094) to make the syntax a bit simpler, but you still need to define up to a specific number of items:

```
type Quadruple = [string, string, number, boolean];
type Value = string;

type Row = [
    ...([] | Quadruple),
    ...([] | Quadruple),
    ...([] | Quadruple),
    ...([] | Quadruple),
    ...([] | Quadruple),
    ...([] | Quadruple),
    ...([] | Quadruple),
    ...Value[]
]

const egRow1: Row = ["id", "name", 1, true, "id2", "name2", 1, true, "id3", "name3", 1, false, "value1", "value2"];
const egRow2: Row = ["id", "name", 1, true, "id2", "name2", 1, true, "value1", "value2"];
const egRow3: Row = ["id", "name", 1, true, "value1", "value2"];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-beta&ssl=17&ssc=65&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrgQwCYCc5gDbQLxQNoDOwKAlgHYDmANFEaZTWXALYBGEKNrA9t1gmQC6AbgCwAKFCQoANQQY4OWsXIUx4iVOgAlbgHcouPBKimoAOksAKPIKgAfWIlTosASiomzl8zbuP4ZDRMCA8vUx8-Bycg11DPcTMLa1towJcQsMTvFP8YjPcEpMjUgOdgwvDk31L8iviqnzkFCFsJQQkJAGNuMiIoCApdPQBGAC4oYcN8ACISJBmaGbIEZghFqBGaYkUl+YAmDeXViEOaLagdiD2kAGYjlbX785oAM3kCa6gZgDd5RRGRz+LUOIm6vX6g2G+wmUyMcwWS0e6xelzQXwRZ2+yKxFyuS2BAKB-1OMzB4h6fWAAyG+lusP00zwCIeJw2ePRBJJgK5ILJwiAA)